# 120VAC to 120VDC @ 0.5A

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I'm working on an arduino project and I need to drive a motor that is rated at 120V and 0.5A with No Load. Since this is a fun project and I'm trying to reuse some parts, hence the 120V dc motor I'm trying to reuse which came from an old coffee grinder.

The input is 120VAC and I'm using a full bridge rectifier but that yields ~169V at the output because of the RMS voltage output.

1)How do I step down the voltage from 169V?

2)Can I use an inductor in series with the capacitor to lower then voltage? If so what formula do I use to calculate the proper size inductor?

3)I noticed in the circuit of the old coffee grinder that it has a power line choke before the rectifier. What purpose does that serve?

[image]

[image]

My knowledge of circuits is rusty so thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Ouch -- you got a 120V/120V isolation transformer to go with that motor of yours?

Comment: 120 V **DC** motors are pretty rare, what kind of motor is it? If it's a universal motor (likely), I'd save yourself some pain and just power it off of AC then use a relay or optoisolator + triac.

Comment: DC motor is from coffee grinder.

Answer (score 5):

Just remove the capacitor, and the rms voltage will go down to 120V.

If your meter responds to average voltage on DC ranges (as most do) then it will read about 10% low (0.636 x peak voltage vs 0.0707), but the actual output voltage will be correct.

Comment: Yes that is an option but my DC motor requires a startup capacitor. Also wouldn't i want a capacitor to filter some of the peaks?

Comment: Startup capacitors are normally only used on induction motors. Are you sure it's a DC motor? What make/model was the coffer grinder? Did it have have a bridge rectifier in it to power the motor?

Comment: I added picture of motor.

Comment: Motor is a Johnson DC971(2)LG (http://disti-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/testco-inc/files/datasheets/8304.pdf)  Here's an example (pulled from a vacuum cleaner) with rectifier pcb. Note **no** filter capacitor on the pcb (though there is place for one) which proves that you don't need one:- http://geb.ebay.com/ImportHubViewItem?itemid=191847299932 another example:- http://www.ebay.com/itm/JOHNSON-MOTOR-DC971-2-LG-120VDC-Motor-for-LG-LUV300B-Upright-Vacuum-EAU60885401-/281733682268